# Transaction timeout while inserting data in azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have written a cloud service in c# that is inserting data in database which uses transaction. While inserting data in local Sql server, its working fine.but when I am inserting data in azure database, transaction timeout issue is coming.

This error is coming after around 10 mins. After searching I found that maximum transaction timeout in azure is 10 mins. How to increase the transaction timeout in azure.